# Jquery div to PHP data

Tags: javascript, php

I have some java script:

```js
 $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/google.hr", function(data) {
            var table_body = "";
   $("#mojetrebam").html(data.status);   
            $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                table_body += "<tr><td>" + k + "</td><td><b>" + v + "</b></td></tr>";
            });});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mojetrebam"></div>
```

My question is, how javascript result ('success') add in some PHP variable
like

```
 $mystatus = "<div id=\"mojetrebam\"></div>";
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. There isn't even any php code in your question. What is it exactly that's going wrong and what do you need?

Comment: Can you explain your scenario and desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code `$mystatus = "<div id=\"mojetrebam\"></div>";` need work.

Be sure that your JAVASCRIPT is in same PHP page wher you have your PHP code.